# Does momentjs and moment-timezone work without an internet connection?

Tags: javascript, momentjs, moment-timezone

I have a webapp that should work normally in a local network, without an internet connection. I use moment-timezone to set the time time according to the server timezone. This works fine with internet. But I was wondering, how does it work without? Where does it get the timezone info to perform the conversion from local to server timezone?

Comment: Have you tried running this on a computer not connected to the internet to see whether it works?

Answer (score 1):

From what I see in moment-timezone github repo data about timezones is stored in JSON files.

[source](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/tree/develop/data)

Comment: Please don't just put a link as an answer. If the link dies, the answer will be gone. Elaborate your answer in detail and add the link as addendum.

Comment: I see that, thank you. But how does it perform certain operations such as converting dates between timezones? Or how does it get your local timezone using moment.tz.guess()? All of this without internet connection?

Comment: You can easily tell if its using internet connection if there are any fetch requests in the source code. The logic is getting quite complex. Is starts obviously from tz function then it calls zone.parse function to add minutes to resulting date. In a zone.parse function there is some kind of loop which calculates right offset from json files.